# How to identify source of data field being updated on web page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

I am trying save data from a web site. There are fields in the html that look like this

```
<td class="data-value" id="v0">yellow</td>
```

where the text `yellow` changes as the user moves the mouse on the page. (To be clear, these fields do not appear in the source if I just do "view-source", but if I use Chrome Develpment Tools and do "inspect element" I can see this.)

I want to find and save the source of this text, which I'm pretty sure is coming from JSON somehow, but I'm not that familiar with Ajax and other tools that the site appears to be using.

So, is there a way to identify where this text is coming from and access it? In other words, I'd like to be able to parse the HTML, and identify what call to make to just see the JSON that is populating this text.

Comment: You can check the Network tab in the Developers Tools. If it comes from ajax, the request will be there (not sure if thats the question :P).

Answer (score 1):

The text may be remotely generated, in which case you will have to simulate the same AJAX requests to access all of the cases.

If the text is stored locally (Javascript), you can access it via events. The first step would be to identify the type of event. Is it a onmouseover or onmousemove? What is the event callback attached to? The page, or the elements being "overed"?

After identifying those criteria with a debugger, you will be able to search the html and javascript references for where these events are being attached in code. That will lead you to a callback function (the one making the decision of which text to post). This callback may perform AJAX, it could have a local table, or it could be a different callback for each element. Any way you go, at that point you will know which file to have your script look at to parse out the data you're looking for.